# Render text from a dictionary/query in Django

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

When I render my queryset onto my Django template it renders the whole queryset
with the curly brackets.Image below

[image]

I just need value of the dictionary not the key. I'm not sure if it's printing it because the whole queryset is a string.

this is my context in  my view, I am joining 2 sentences into a list and then trying to render them to the template

```
 eng_sentance_flash = model.objects.filter(show_sentance = True).values('sentance_eng')[:1]  #limit 1
 esp_sentance_flash = model.objects.filter(show_sentance = True).values('sentance_esp')[:1]  
 zip_flash_sentances = list(zip(eng_sentance_flash,esp_sentance_flash))

 return render(request, template_name, {'sentances_list': user_sentances,'zip_flash_sentances':zip_flash_sentances})
```

And here is the code where I am trying to print it to the screen

```
  {% for rand in zip_flash_sentances %}            
               <p>{{ rand.0 |safe }}</p> 
               <p>{{ rand.1 |safe }}</p>           

   {% endfor %}
```

And the output looks like this on the screen

```
{'sentance_eng': 'Croagh Patrick is the sacred mountain of Ireland, where St. Patrick is supposed to fast for 44 days when he came to Christianize Ireland in the 5th century'}

{'sentance_esp': 'Croagh Patrick es la montaña sagrada de Irlanda, donde se supone que San Patricio ayunó durante 44 días cuando vino a cristianizar Irlanda en el siglo V'}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The items are wrapped in a dictionary, you could, strictly speaking unwrap these with `{{ rand.0.sentance_eng|safe }}`, etc. But you can make it more efficient by querying both columns in a single query, unpack the first item out of the `QuerySet`, and let Django to the zipping by using [**`.values_list(..)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#values-list):

```
zip_flash_sentances = model.objects.filter(
    show_sentance=True
).values_list('sentance_eng', 'stance_esp').first()

return render(request, template_name, {'sentances_list': user_sentances,'zip_flash_sentances':zip_flash_sentances})
```

The `.first()` will thus take the first item, and unwrap it out of the `QuerySet`. If no such first item exists, then it will be `None`.

In the template, you can render this with:

```
<p>{{ zip_flash_sentances.0 |safe }}</p>
<p>{{ zip_flash_sentances.1 |safe }}</p>
```